# How to obtain a missing part?

Tags: piece-information, replacement-parts, ideas

I'm building the [21320 LEGO Ideas Dinosaur Fossils](https://brickset.com/sets/21320-1/Dinosaur-Fossils) set. Looks like there is a part missing. I only have one of the part in the attached image. How can I identify the part number and obtain it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is [6047220: Plate W. Bow 2X2X2/3](https://brickset.com/parts/6047220/plate-w-bow-2x2x2-3). You can get it from [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=122934&idColor=1&view=buy&ccName=6047220#T=S&C=1&O=%7B%22color%22:1,%22ss%22:%22FR%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D), **but first** try the official [LEGO replacement parts service](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/replacementparts). They will most probably send you a free replacement part and with your report you are contributing to the quality assurance project of LEGO, helping them avoid such cases in the future.

P.S. Still before, check the box, the bags, the building area and any partially completed builds for mistakes (like using it instead of a [Plate W. Bow **1**X2X2/3](https://brickset.com/parts/6034044/plate-w-bow-1x2x2-3)). There is a non-negligible chance your part is hiding somewhere, and everybody is much better off if you find it before you take the other steps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've submitted a request to the replacement service.

Comment: Aww, looks like my edit was too late. Nevertheless, welcome to Bricks.SE, feel free to have a look around and take the [tour] or read the [help] to get yourself acquainted with the site!

Comment: My first reaction was to look for it for a while inside bags and around the build area. I examined the half-built model too to see if I used it already but I didn't want to take it all apart only to find out it's nowhere to be found. However, the delivery time is quite long so I might end up taking it apart anyway. Thanks again for your speedy help.

Comment: I assume this is why Lego often includes extras of tiny parts.